# Unable to alter table in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have the following fundamental problem in my first approach to SQLite.
I create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test(ID INTEGER);
```

I can insert data

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1);
```

But I am not able to rename

```
ALTER TABLE test RENAME TO new_test;
```

Or to add a column

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN year INTEGER;
```

In both cases I get the following error:

```
SQL error: near "ALTER": syntax error
```

Comment: Your code works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7cc97336225374dbc91b46bdeafa439b As you described your issue it is not reproducible.

Comment: @forpas Well my guess then is that the OP is using an older version of SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not permit much DDL to be done on a table after the table has been created.  This includes renaming or adding new columns.  To do what you want above, create a new table and populate it using the old table's data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE newtest (ID INTEGER, year INTEGER);

-- can also populate the year column here
INSERT INTO newtest (ID)
SELECT ID
FROM test;

DROP TABLE test;  -- no need for this table anymore
```

Comment: Hi, I see how the solution works, but in my understanding SQLite should at least be able to permit adding columns and renaming: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-alter-table/. isn't what you say conflicting with most of the documentation online?

Comment: SQLite supports ALTER TABLE ... RENAME TABLE ... since version 3.1.0 (2005-01-21) and ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ... since version 3.2.0 (2005-03-21).